# How to find the side lines of the field of text

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a processed image with text in it and I want to find the coordinates of lines which would touch the edges of the text field, but would not cross it and would strech through the whole side of text. Image below shows what I need (*the red lines I drew show the example of what coordinates I want to find on a raw image*):
[image]

It is not so straightforward, I can't just find the edges of processed field of text (upper left, upper right and so on), because it may be, f.e. a start of a paragraph (*this is just an example of the possible scenario*):

[image]

The sides of the text form a straight line, it is the top and bottom edges may be curved, so that could make things easier.

**What is the best way to do this?**

Any method I can think of is either not practical, inneficient or may usually give false results.

The raw image in case someone needs for processing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to find the convex hull of all of the text. After we find the convex hull we find its sides. If the side Has a big change in its y coordinate and a small change in the x coordinate (i.e. the line has a high slope) we will consider it as a side line.

The resulted image:

[image]

the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def getConvexCoord(convexH, ind):
    yLines = []
    xLine = []
    for index in range(len(ind[0])):
        convexIndex = ind[0][index]

        # Get point
        if convexIndex == len(convexH) - 1:
            p0 = convexH[0]
            p1 = convexH[convexIndex]
        else:
            p0 = convexH[convexIndex]
            p1 = convexH[convexIndex + 1]

        # Add y corrdinate
        yLines.append(p0[0, 1])
        yLines.append(p1[0, 1])
        xLine.append(p0[0, 0])
        xLine.append(p1[0, 0])
    return yLines,xLine

def filterLine(line):
    sortX = sorted(line)
    # Find the median
    xMedian = np.median(sortX)
    while ((sortX[-1] - sortX[0]) > I.shape[0]):

        # Find out which is farther from the median and discard
        lastValueDistance = np.abs(xMedian - sortX[-1])
        firstValueDistance = np.abs(xMedian - sortX[0])
        if lastValueDistance > firstValueDistance:

            # Discard last
            del sortX[-1]
        else:
            # Discard first
            del sortX[0]

    # Now return mixX and maxX
    return max(sortX),min(sortX)


# Read image
Irgb = cv2.imread('text.jpg')
I = Irgb[:,:,0]

# Threshold
ret, Ithresh = cv2.threshold(I,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find the convex hull of the text
textPixels = np.nonzero(Ithresh)
textPixels = zip(textPixels[1],textPixels[0])
convexH = cv2.convexHull(np.asarray(textPixels))

# Find the side edges in the convex hull
m = []
for index in range((len(convexH))-1):

    # Calculate the angle of the line
    point0 = convexH[index]
    point1 = convexH[index+1]
    if(point1[0,0]-point0[0,0]) == 0:
        m.append(90)
    else:
        m.append(float((point1[0,1]-point0[0,1]))/float((point1[0,0]-point0[0,0])))

# Final line
point0 = convexH[index+1]
point1 = convexH[0]
if(point1[0,0]-point0[0,0]) == 0:
    m.append(90)
else:
    m.append(np.abs(float((point1[0,1]-point0[0,1]))/float((point1[0,0]-point0[0,0]))))

# Take all the lines with the big m
ind1 = np.where(np.asarray(m)>1)
ind2 = np.where(np.asarray(m)<-1)

# For both lines find min Y an max Y
yLines1,xLine1 = getConvexCoord(convexH,ind1)
yLines2,xLine2 = getConvexCoord(convexH,ind2)
yLines = yLines1 + yLines2

# Filter xLines. If we the difference between the min and the max are more than 1/2 the size of the image we filter it out
minY = np.min(np.asarray(yLines))
maxY = np.max(np.asarray(yLines))

maxX1,minX1 = filterLine(xLine1)
maxX2,minX2 = filterLine(xLine2)

# Change final lines to have minY and maxY
line1 = ((minX1,minY),(maxX1,maxY))
line2 = ((maxX2,minY),(minX2,maxY))

# Plot lines
IrgbWithLines = Irgb
cv2.line(IrgbWithLines,line1[0],line1[1],(0, 0, 255),2)
cv2.line(IrgbWithLines,line2[0],line2[1],(0, 0, 255),2)
```

**Remarks**:
The algorithm assumes that the y coordinate change is bigger than the x coordinate change. This will not be true for very high perspective distortions (45 degrees). In this case maybe you should use k-means on the slopes and take the group with the higher slopes as the vertical lines.

Answer (score 0):

The lines marked in red colour on the sides could be found using image closing operation.
Please find below the matlab output after imclose operation with structuring element of type square and size 4.'[image: the result of code segment]

The matlab code is as follow:

I = rgb2gray(imread('image.jpg'));
imshow(I); title('image');

Ibinary = im2bw(I);
figure,imshow(Ibinary);

se = strel('square',4);

Iclose = imclose(Ibinary,se);
figure,imshow(Iclose); title('side lines');

Comment: The lines here I drew to show an example of what vector/coordinates I want to find on a raw image. I need the lines which would touch the sides of an image, stretching through it all and not crossing the text. You just found the lines I drew as an example. Sorry if my explanaton in the question was not clear.